# Error en consume de Servicio web (org.xml.sax.SAXParseException)

Tags: java, xml, webservice, sax

Alguna idea de como corregir el error:

> (org.xml.sax.SAXParseException)org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; El contenido no está permitido en el
>   prólogo

Cuando intento consumir un servicio web, en la linea 3 del código expuesto abajo:

```
DocumentBuilder builder = null;
builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();            
Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getArchivo()));
```

Comment: ¿Estas seguro que result.getArchivo es un string, y te esta devolviendo algún valor? Saludos

Comment: Por favor, revisa el contenido de `result.getArchivo` e inclúyelo en la pregunta.